# Initialize variable with default value in python

Tags: python

I have a function like this:

```
def __init__(self, out_file='out.csv', tmp_folder=None):
    self.tmp_folder = tmp_folder if tmp_folder != None else join(getcwd(), '__tmp__')
```

I was wondering if ther exists a smarter way to do it, something like js:

```
    self.tmp_folder = tmp_folder || join(getcwd(), '__tmp__')
```

Comment: `tmp_folder or join(getcwd(), '__tmp__') `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `None` evaluates to `False`, you could always do:

```
def __init__(self, out_file='out.csv', tmp_folder=None):
    self.tmp_folder = tmp_folder or join(getcwd(), '__tmp__')
```

Note however that this will assign `self.tmp_folder` to `join(getcwd(), '__tmp__')` if `tmp_folder` is any falsey value (`False`, `0`, `[]`, `{}`, etc.)

Comment: Gee, as soon as I finished writing the example I saw it, jeje

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like this:

```
self.tmp_folder = tmp_folder or join(getcwd(), '__tmp__')
```

You just use `or` instead of `||`